# Disable Android WebView WebRTC

Tags: android, webview

Fresh Cromium WebView supports WebRTC and I want to disable it. Chrome app can allow do this in Chrome, so it seems not to be impossible.
I was researching a lot and didn't find appropriate solution for this.
Any help would be appreciated.

upd. still unsolved. looks like even reflection does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to say, but the conclusion I came to is the same.

You cannot disable WebRTC in the Android WebView right now. This is an insane and massive oversight. I sincerely hope that Google will add this feature ASAP, especially with the WebRTC leak in the wild: https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips

Comment: is it still not possible to disable it?