# How to disable WebRTC in GeckoView

Tags: android, webrtc, geckoview

**When using GeckoView, is it possible to disable WebRTC? Either programmatically or at build-time (e.g. in `build.gradle`)?**

**Context:**

We are building an Android app where we would like to run mini-web-apps without internet access in a webview. When using the system webview, it's not possible to restrict internet access because [the webapp can always use WebRTC to circumvent the internet restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174648/disable-android-webview-webrtc).

So, we are thinking about switching to GeckoView, but are not sure if this will help.

**Research:**

In Firefox, it seems to be possible to [disable WebRTC using about:config](https://www.lifewire.com/disable-webrtc-4707229#toc-how-to-disable-webrtc-in-firefox), but in [GeckoView's API](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/package-summary.html), I could neither find a way to set `about:config` preferences, nor an API that directly disables WebRTC.

For normal internet requests, it [seems to be possible to block them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71205677/block-images-from-particular-domain-in-geckoview-android).

Answer (score 5):

You can disable WebRTC by setting the `media.peerconnection.enabled` preference to false using the GeckoView `GeckoRuntimeSettings` class.

```
GeckoRuntimeSettings.Builder builder = new GeckoRuntimeSettings.Builder();
builder.preferences().setBoolean("media.peerconnection.enabled", false);
GeckoRuntime geckoRuntime = GeckoRuntime.create(this, builder.build());
```

This will disable WebRTC for the entire app.

Alternatively, at build-time -- You can disable WebRTC by adding the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<meta-data android:name="org.mozilla.geckoview.WebRTC" android:value="false" />
```

Otherwise, you can add the following line to your `build.gradle` file to disable WebRTC for all flavors of your app:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [geckoviewWebRTC: "false"]
    }
}
```

And then add the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<meta-data android:name="org.mozilla.geckoview.WebRTC" android:value="${geckoviewWebRTC}" />
```

This will disable WebRTC for all flavors of your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer -- pity the bounty ran out exactly the day you provided this answer ;) The other answer is also interesting, however, as it could help to reduce the apk size if one is shipping a "restricted" geckoview.

Comment: Thanks! The code snippet using `GeckoRuntimeSettings` doesn't compile though because [there is no `preferences()` method on `GeckoRuntimeSettings.Builder`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoRuntimeSettings.Builder.html)

Comment: Where in the AndroidManifest do I need to put the `<meta-data>`? Inside the `<manifest>` tag? Inside the `<application>` tag?

Comment: @hpk42 Its okay but I had submitted the solution when the bounty was still 50 mins away till it expired.

Comment: `.preferences()` method not found. what gecko version you used?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/mobile/android/geckoview/build.gradle#l107 it seems possible to recompile without the **MOZ_WEBRTC** variable set, to exclude all WebRTC sources from the build.

It maybe worth a try.

Please take a look [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/contributor/geckoview-quick-start.html#custom-mozconfig-with-android-studio) to see how to rebuild the library customizing the configuration

Comment: 1. What's the exact text I have to put into the `mozconfig` file? I just downloaded the geckoview sources, and there is no line mentioning `MOZ_WEBRTC` or `substs` in the `mozconfig file.    2. How much do I have to compile myself for this? Is it enough to build only the Java code (i.e. artifact build) or do I need to also compile the C++ code myself? Or is it even enough to include geckoview as a dependency in my `build.gradle`, and somehow set this variable?